# Is it possible to grep the quickfix window in Vim?

Tags: vim, grep

Let’s say I use the ag.vim plugin to search for the string `disabled` through multiple files. It returns me some results in the quickfix window:

```
1 first_file.rb|1 col 1| disabled something something
2 second_file.rb|1 col 2| disabled another something
```

Is it possible to pick the quickfix results as an input, grep through them, and open results in new quickfix window? In other words, if I would enter `:quickfix_grep first_file`, new quickfix would pop up with only one entry:

```
1 first_file.rb|1 col 1| disabled something something
```

Comment: what do you mean by "new quickfix"? there is only one quickfix, the "new" will overwrite "old", do you mean that?

Comment: @Kent yes, i did mean that

Comment: The quickfix window can be searched with `/` and `?` just like any other window.

Comment: @romainl i know that. but i thought it would be fancy to filter it. with huge result list, there's still too much noise.

Comment: @romainl also - I'm aware that Ag has feature to specify filename pattern, but I was wondering if there's bit more general and vim specific solution. I'm using quickfix for other things too - e.g. fugitive log.

Comment: Then it's a search pattern problem or a file filtering problem. No, there's no native way to do what you want but the current quickfix list is available through `getqflist()`.

Comment: @ArnisL. what is you goal? you want to get one certain entry from "old" quickfix or you want to take one entry of old QF, get the text as pattern and do another grep?

Comment: @Kent i want to filter quickfix results by pattern

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Update

A vim plugin has been written for this requirement: https://github.com/sk1418/QFGrep

---

#### Original Answer:

My understanding of your goal is:

> Your grep result is somehow huge in your quickfix, you want to narrow
>   your view of it. by entering a command with regex, filter the grep
>   result. The filtered result should also be displayed in QuickFix
>   window, so that you could open/jump to  the file.

If the above is what you want, check out the following:

source this function and the command line:

```
function! GrepQuickFix(pat)
  let all = getqflist()
  for d in all
    if bufname(d['bufnr']) !~ a:pat && d['text'] !~ a:pat
        call remove(all, index(all,d))
    endif
  endfor
  call setqflist(all)
endfunction
command! -nargs=* GrepQF call GrepQuickFix(<q-args>)
```

then after your grep/ack/whatever show stuffs in your quickfix, you could type

```
:GrepQF <regex>
```

to do filtering in your quickfix.

Here I add an GIF animation. I am using `Ack` instead of `grep`, but it makes no difference. The given regex will match filename and the text showing in quickfix. I did filtering twice to show that.

[image]

hope it helps.

Comment: that's just purrrrrfect! btw, how did you make that gif?

Comment: @ArnisL. well, this small script is not a real "plugin". but I am glad if you think it is helpful.

Comment: i don't consider numbers.vim plugin to be a "real plugin" too. anyway - it's just a name, a status. main thing is that it helps :)

Answer (score 10):

### New official vim plugin [*cfilter*](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/pack/dist/opt/cfilter/plugin/cfilter.vim)

Since [21.8.2018 (patch: 8.1.0311)](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/8c5e0093c9badced73e382915fb024a5c3ea463b) the plugin *cfilter* is distributed with vim in `$VIMRUNTIME`. It is documented under `:h cfilter-plugin`.

Load plugin *cfilter* when needed or load it always in your vimrc

```
:packadd cfilter
```

Filter quickfix list with

```
:Cfilter DPUST
```

Answer (score 5):

My solution to this problem has always been to make the quickfix
buffer modifiable *by default*:

```
:autocmd BufReadPost quickfix set modifiable
```

(The above command is to be put in the `.vimrc` file.)

Doing this opens a whole range of possibilities for any appropriate
edits of the grepping results, such as removing unrelated entries
manually or by filtering using the `:global` and `:vglobal` commands
(which provide the functionality desired in the question for free);
grouping and reordering related entries; adding blank lines or
comments in free form; etc.

Comment: shortcuts: `:set ma`, `:set noma`

Comment: @ArnisL.:  The whole point is that if you put the above auto-command in your `.vimrc` file, then you don't need to manually set the `modifiable` option.  Every time the quickfix list is opened, it will already be made modifiable.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a shorter & neater version of @Kent's answer:

```
function! GrepQuickFix(pat)
  call setqflist(filter(getqflist(), "bufname(v:val['bufnr']) !~# a:pat"))
endfunction
command! -nargs=* GrepQF call GrepQuickFix(<q-args>)
```

It is the same code, just neater and shorter, I don't believe it deserves a separate plugin.