# Quickfix list, how to add and remove entries

Tags: vim

In vim I ususally use the quickfix list as a type of todo list to fix errors or to refactor code. But I have a few problems in my workflow:

- If I have to jump forward with `:cn` multiple times to compare others parts of the code, finding the last edited entry with `:cp` is difficult. `:cw` helps, but on bigger lists, it gets difficult, too. Removing fixed entries would be helpful.
- On refactoring I encounter sometimes pieces of code I want to return later. Using global marks is ok, but adding the current position to the quickfix list would be more helpful.

So I hoped to find a simple command with `:help quicktext` to add a position to the quickfix list or to remove an already fixed entry. But all I could find is `:cbuffer` or `:caddb`. But on editing the buffer after `:cw` I get a message, it is not modifiable. The help text offers the following solution (but I do not really want to write temporary files):

> Note: Making changes in the quickfix window has no effect on the list of
>   errors.  'modifiable' is off to avoid making changes.  If you delete or insert
>   lines anyway, the relation between the text and the error number is messed up.
>   If you really want to do this, you could write the contents of the quickfix
>   window to a file and use ":cfile" to have it parsed and used as the new error
>   list.

And maybe with `:cad` one could add the current line? Or has anyone an alternative workflow in mind?

Comment: You may want to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15406138/is-it-possible-to-grep-vims-quickfix

Comment: If you use Unimpaired plugin, you can navigate using `]q`, `[q`, `]Q` and `[Q` instead of `:cn`, `:cp`, `:clast` and `:cfirst`

Comment: What a painful question(so upvoted). This `getqflist()` API takes me 3 days to fully understand its usage...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found your question while looking particularly for the ability to remove items from the quickfix list. I'm not super good at vimscript, so there's probably a more elegant solution, but here's what I came up with.

This overrides `dd` in the quickfix list (which is pretty much useless anyway, since `modifiable` is off) to remove the current line (the current line of the cursor, not the current quickfix item) from the quickfix list.

I couldn't figure out how to programmatically determine the current quickfix item, which is how I settled on using `dd`, to make it more obvious that it applies to the line of the cursor.

I hope you might find this useful.

```
" When using `dd` in the quickfix list, remove the item from the quickfix list.
function! RemoveQFItem()
  let curqfidx = line('.') - 1
  let qfall = getqflist()
  call remove(qfall, curqfidx)
  call setqflist(qfall, 'r')
  execute curqfidx + 1 . "cfirst"
  :copen
endfunction
:command! RemoveQFItem :call RemoveQFItem()
" Use map <buffer> to only map dd in the quickfix window. Requires +localmap
autocmd FileType qf map <buffer> dd :RemoveQFItem<cr>
```

UPDATE: I've fixed a few issues I've found with the above function.

Comment: Nice, this is a very helpful small plugin. I've copied it into ~/.vim/plugin/quickfix_dd.vim and it worked like a charm.

Comment: I went one step further and made it into a plugin. [Here you go](https://github.com/TamaMcGlinn/quickfixdd)

Comment: I just fixed a few bugs in the script; see [#1](https://github.com/TamaMcGlinn/quickfixdd/issues/1)

Comment: Wow, awesome! Thanks @TamaMcGlinn!

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm not using https://github.com/kevinhwang91/nvim-bqf

Answer (score 17):

### Update: New official vim plugin [*cfilter*](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/pack/dist/opt/cfilter/plugin/cfilter.vim)

Since [21.8.2018 (patch: 8.1.0311)](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/8c5e0093c9badced73e382915fb024a5c3ea463b) the plugin *cfilter* is distributed in `$VIMRUNTIME` itself. It is documented under `:h cfilter-plugin`.

Load plugin *cfilter* when needed or load it always in your vimrc

```
:packadd cfilter
```

Filter quickfix list with

```
:Cfilter DPUST
```

Answer (score 9):

Adding and removing entries to and from the quickfix list is usually done with `:help setqflist()` and `:help getqflist()`.

You also have `:help :caddexpr`, which contains an example that looks a lot like what you are trying to do, but there's unfortunately no symmetrical `:cremoveexpr`.

---

Since we are at it, my plugin [vim-qf](https://github.com/romainl/vim-qf) lets you filter, save, modify, combine, and restore quickfix lists so it *may* be useful for you. Adding/removing arbitrary items from a qf/loc list sounds like a possible feature by the way…

Comment: Thanks. I've tried `:caddexpr` but could not restrict it for the current line. Found https://github.com/jceb/vim-editqf as a nice plugin for adding. And I'll take a look into the reject function from your plugin.

Comment: Aha, I found you! You're the first author of the famous plugin vim-qf :) Great to see you here, a much more formal one than the other answers.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a shorter way of achieving the same thing without having to use a plugin or define a function...

Just pop this into `ftplugin/qf.vim`. For Neovim, put this file at `~/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin/qf.vim`.

This syntax adds a `dd` keybinding to the quickfix file type only. This removes the current line from the list.

For example, use `:cope` to open a quickfix buffer and try `dd` there.

```
nnoremap <buffer> <silent> dd
  \ <Cmd>call setqflist(filter(getqflist(), {idx -> idx != line('.') - 1}), 'r') <Bar> cc<CR>
```

**Note:** I *believe* the `<Cmd>` map is only available in Neovim, In which case you'd just remove that and add a `:` if you're in regular vim.

Answer (score 2):

`:set modifiable` or `:set ma` makes the buffer modifiable so you can `dd` lines out of the quickfix list.

Comment: This doesn't exactly work. Sure this will remove lines from the quick fix list, but if you then try to navigate to the quick fix item, you will be sent to the wrong file.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone interested, here is my way for Neovim. It deletes the item under the cursor, updates the list, and moves the cursor to the item that was below the now deleted item. Cheers.

```
-- quickfix list delete keymap
function Remove_qf_item()
  local curqfidx = vim.fn.line('.')
  local qfall = vim.fn.getqflist()

  -- Return if there are no items to remove
  if #qfall == 0 then return end

  -- Remove the item from the quickfix list
  table.remove(qfall, curqfidx)
  vim.fn.setqflist(qfall, 'r')

  -- Reopen quickfix window to refresh the list
  vim.cmd('copen')  

  -- If not at the end of the list, stay at the same index, otherwise, go one up.
  local new_idx = curqfidx < #qfall and curqfidx or math.max(curqfidx - 1, 1)

  -- Set the cursor position directly in the quickfix window
  local winid = vim.fn.win_getid() -- Get the window ID of the quickfix window
  vim.api.nvim_win_set_cursor(winid, {new_idx, 0})
end

vim.cmd("command! RemoveQFItem lua Remove_qf_item()")
vim.api.nvim_command("autocmd FileType qf nnoremap <buffer> dd :RemoveQFItem<cr>")
```

Answer (score 1):

Vimscript has a python-like way to select array ranges, so you can also select the current quickfix list using `[n:n]` as the index.

```
:call setqflist(getqflist()[1:])
```

...will remove the first item from the list.

```
:call setqflist(getqflist()[:0])
```

...will remove the last.

You can also concat arrays using `+` so...

```
:call setqflist(getqflist()[1:] + getqflist()[:0])
```

...works as well!

Answer (score 0):

The solution I'm using is below.  I don't like remapping 'dd', since '.' won't repeat the command afterwards.  Plus, other ways of modifying the list won't work as expected, like for instance, ':g/{pattern}/d'.  The solution below simply allows normal vim modification to the list, while keeping the locations updated.  Lastly, in the solution below, I haven't mapped the function 'AddLocationToQuickfixList' to anything, since key mappings are highly personal.  You can map it to whatever you like.  When it's called, it will add your current location to the quickfix list.

```
function! AddLocationToQuickfixList()
    let l:current_location = {'pattern': '', 'valid': 1, 'vcol': 0, 'nr': 0, 'module': '', 'type': ''}
    let l:current_location['bufnr'] = bufnr('%')
    let l:current_location['lnum'] = line('.')
    let l:current_location['end_lnum'] = line('.')
    let l:current_location['col'] = 1
    let l:current_location['end_col'] = len(getline('.')) + 1
    let l:current_location['text'] = trim(getline('.'))
    let l:qflist = getqflist()
    if index(l:qflist, l:current_location) == -1
        copen
        call add(l:qflist, l:current_location)
        call setqflist(l:qflist, 'r')
    endif
endfunction

function! WindowIsList()
    if WindowIsLocationList() || WindowIsQuickfixList()
        return 1
    endif
    return 0
endfunction

function! WindowIsLocationList()
    let l:qfvar = getwininfo(win_getid())[0]['quickfix']
    let l:llvar = getwininfo(win_getid())[0]['loclist']
    if l:llvar == 1 && l:qfvar == 1
        return 1
    endif
    return 0
endfunction

function! WindowIsQuickfixList()
    let l:qfvar = getwininfo(win_getid())[0]['quickfix']
    let l:llvar = getwininfo(win_getid())[0]['loclist']
    if l:llvar == 0 && l:qfvar == 1
        return 1
    endif
    return 0
endfunction

function! UpdateList()
    "Determine whether or not the current list is a location list or quickfix list.
    "  In the event it's neither, return.
    if WindowIsLocationList()
        let l:list_type = "location"
    elseif WindowIsQuickfixList()
        let l:list_type = "quickfix"
    else
        return
    endif
    "Store the line number of the cursor.
    "  The list will have to be reloaded, which moves the cursor to the top.
    "  This will be used to restore its location.
    let l:iniline = line('.')
    "Get the current contents of the list.
    "  Note that this will include any deleted lines.
    "  When a line is deleted from a list, only the window text is updated by default.
    if l:list_type == "location"
        let l:old_list = getloclist(0)
    elseif l:list_type == "quickfix"
        let l:old_list = getqflist()
    endif
    "Get a list of all the lines visible in the list's window.
    "  Note that this list will NOT include any deleted lines.
    "  This will be used to filter the list contents.
    let l:window_text = getline(1, '$')
    "Create an empty list to populate with list items.
    "  Any item in the old_list that gets to stay will be added to this list.
    let l:new_list = []
    "Loop through the old_list.
    for l:list_item in l:old_list
        "Using the list_item, produce its corresponding display text (what the user sees in the list's window).
        let l:buffer_name = expand("#" .. l:list_item['bufnr'])
        if l:list_item['end_lnum'] == l:list_item['lnum']
            let l:line_numbers = l:list_item['lnum']
        else
            let l:line_numbers = l:list_item['lnum'] .. "-" .. l:list_item['end_lnum']
        endif
        let l:column_numbers = l:list_item['col'] .. "-" .. l:list_item['end_col']
        let l:preview_text = trim(l:list_item['text'])
        let l:list_item_display_text = l:buffer_name .. "|" .. l:line_numbers .. " col " .. l:column_numbers .. "| " .. l:preview_text
        "If the list item's display text is found in the current window text (ie, it has not been deleted by the user), add the list_item to new_list.
        if index(l:window_text, l:list_item_display_text) != -1
            call add(l:new_list, l:list_item)
        endif
    endfor
    "Update the contents of the list.
    if l:list_type == "location"
        call setloclist(0, l:new_list, 'r')
    elseif l:list_type == "quickfix"
        call setqflist(l:new_list, 'r')
    endif
    "Restore the cursor's line number.
    exe "exe " .. l:iniline
    "Make sure the list is modifiable.
    set modifiable
endfunction

autocmd BufWinEnter * if WindowIsList() | set modifiable | endif
autocmd TextChanged * if WindowIsList() | call UpdateList() | endif
```

EDIT: I added the BufWinEnter autocmd to handle setting the first instance of a list modifiable, and I removed 1 unnecessary line of code from the 'UpdateList' function.

Answer (score 0):

I add some features on accepted answer that supporting `count operation` and `visual operation`.

You can use `2dd` to remove two rows, also using `dd` to remove selected rows.

```
" When using `dd` in the quickfix list, remove the item from the quickfix list.
function! RemoveQFItem(mode) range abort
  let l:qf_list = getqflist()

  " distinguish mode for getting delete index and delete count
  if a:mode == 'v'
    let l:del_qf_idx = getpos("'<")[1] - 1
    let l:del_ct = getpos("'>")[1] - l:del_qf_idx
  else
    let l:del_qf_idx = line('.') - 1
    let l:del_ct = v:count > 1 ? v:count : 1
  endif

  " delete lines and update quickfix
  for item in range(l:del_ct)
    call remove(l:qf_list, l:del_qf_idx)
  endfor
  call setqflist(l:qf_list, 'r')

  if len(l:qf_list) > 0
    execute l:del_qf_idx + 1 . 'cfirst'
    copen
  else
    cclose
  endif
endfunction

autocmd FileType qf nmap <buffer> dd :call RemoveQFItem('n')<cr>
autocmd FileType qf vmap <buffer> dd :call RemoveQFItem('v')<cr>
```